# Will code written in this style be optimized out by RVO in C++11?

Tags: optimization, c++11

I grew up in the days when passing around structures was bad mojo because they are often large, so pointers were always the way to go.  Now that C++11 has quite good RVO (right value optimization), I'm wondering if code like the following will be efficient.

As you can see, my class has a bunch of vector structures (not pointers to them).  The constructor accepts value structures and stores them away.

My -hope- is that the compiler will use move semantics so that there really is no copying of data going on; the constructor will (when possible) just assume ownership of the values passed in.

Does anyone know if this is true, and happens automagically, or do I need a move constructor with the && syntax and so on?

```
// ParticleVertex
//
// Class that represents the particle vertices

class ParticleVertex : public Vertex
{
  public:
    D3DXVECTOR4   _vertexPosition;
    D3DXVECTOR2   _vertexTextureCoordinate;
    D3DXVECTOR3   _vertexDirection;
    D3DXVECTOR3   _vertexColorMultipler;

    ParticleVertex(D3DXVECTOR4   vertexPosition,
                   D3DXVECTOR2   vertexTextureCoordinate,
                   D3DXVECTOR3   vertexDirection,
                   D3DXVECTOR3   vertexColorMultipler)
    {
        _vertexPosition          = vertexPosition;
        _vertexTextureCoordinate = vertexTextureCoordinate;
        _vertexDirection         = vertexDirection;
        _vertexColorMultipler    = vertexColorMultipler;
    }

    virtual const D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 * GetVertexDeclaration() const
    {
        return particleVertexDeclarations;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please, use initialization list at the constructor instead of assigments in its body.

Comment: RVO stands for return value optimisation.

Comment: `D3DXVECTOR4` interface and implementation matter to determine how you should pass it.  In this case, `D3DXVECTOR4` is a POD `struct` of 4 `float`s.  `std::move` and `&&` will have little impact on how it is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed you should trust the compiler to optimally "move" the structures:

- [Want Speed? Pass By Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

> Guideline: Don’t copy your function arguments. Instead, pass them by value and let the compiler do the copying

In this case, you'd move the arguments into the constructor call:

```
ParticleVertex myPV(std::move(pos),
               std::move(textureCoordinate),
               std::move(direction),
               std::move(colorMultipler));
```

In many contexts, the `std::move` will be *implicit*, e.g.

```
D3DXVECTOR4 getFooPosition() { 
     D3DXVECTOR4 result;
     // bla

     return result; // NRVO, std::move only required with MSVC
}

ParticleVertex myPV(getFooPosition(), // implicit rvalue-reference moved
```

Comment: `move` won't save anything here -- those structures are aggregates.

Comment: @BillyONeal I don't actually do D3DX programming. In that case, the question seems to be... ill-posed. My answer should explain the general case (e.g. when passing `ParticleVertex` objects) and inspecting the generated code always trumps any guideline :)

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused - if I'm using VS2012, which supports C++11, when do you need the std::move() in the constructor?

I could just check the generated assembly, but I'd prefer to know from the language spec and compiler support what's actually -supposed- to happen.

Comment: @Dave MSVC just requires an explicit (redundant) `std::move` on return by value, AFAIK. With the other part, start here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B-faq%5D+rvalue+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 0):

**RVO** means *Return Value Optimization* not Right value optimization.

RVO is a optimization performed by the compiler when the return of a function is by value, and its clear that the code returns a temporary object created in the body, so the copy can be avoided. The function returns the created object directly.

What C++11 introduces is *Move Semantics*. Move semantics allows us to "move" the resource from a certain temporary to a target object.
But, move implies that the object wich the resource comes from, is in a unusable state after the move. This is not the case (I think) you want in your class, because the vertex data is used by the class, even if the user calls to this function or not.
So, use the common return by const reference to avoid copies.

On the other hand,, DirectX provides handles to the resources (Pointers), not the real resource. Pointers are basic types,its copying is cheap, so don't worry about performance. In your case, you are using 2d/3d vectors. Its copying is cheap too.

Personally, I think that returning a pointer to an internal resource is a very bad idea, always. I think that in this case the best aproach is to return by const reference.